# MySQL query to get duration for each stage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

| listing | stage | status | timeInMillis | desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 0 | 0 | 1653429998443 | part-1 |
| 121 | 0 | 0 | 1653429998453 | part-2 |
| 121 | 0 | 1 | 1653429998696 | part-1-complete |
| 121 | 0 | 1 | 1653429998753 | part-2-complete |
| 121 | 1 | 0 | 1653429998794 | ... |
| 121 | 1 | 0 | 1653429998811 | ... |
| 121 | 1 | 1 | 1653429999069 | ... |
| 121 | 1 | 1 | 1653429999090 | ... |
| 164 | .. | .. | .. | ... |

Stages can be `0`, or `1`. Status `0` means `Started`, `1` means complete. For this query desc isn't as important. I need to generate report of whole table and find duration for each stage of each listing. For example duration for `121` and stage `0` is `(1653429998753 - 1653429998443)` and stage 1 is `(1653429999090 - 1653429998794)`. Is it possible to get this with just query or have to work around with procedure/functions? Having hard time to wrap around my head to get this query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? The way to solve this is with window functions, which were introduced in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT listing, stage,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN timeInMillis END) -
       MIN(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN timeInMillis END) AS difference
FROM tablename
GROUP BY listing, stage;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=479a52c6682f0cdd5e68b1ed0b9dde50).

Comment: This is neat, however,  I can't use `CASE` or `IF` due to limitation imposed by driver I use.

Comment: @cosmos which driver would not support standard SQL like CASE? Any other solution with joins or subqueries would have bad performance on a large dataset. A solution would be to create a view in your MySql server with the above query and then select directly from that view: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7b750bdf7971b54b385f470c8b1b480

Comment: it's custom built driver. however, the view idea worked for me.